# How to get this glass shatter effect to work on multiple divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Situation**

I have this glass shatter effect simulation that involves some basic javacsript code and right now it works fine; When you click on the logo, the glass shatters accordingly and then a new unshattered logo re-appears in its place.

Take a look at the **jSFiddle** here:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/9n9ft9ks/3/

**Problem**

Right now, there's only one logo on the page. ***I need there to be more than one logo***, probably like five (of the same Floyd's autoglass logos) ***all on the same page***, all with the same onClick glass shatter effect.  But when I try to do this myself  - put more than one (of the same logo) on the page, the code just breaks.

**How I tried to fix it**

The logo with the glass shatter effect is a div called "`#container`". So since I want more than one of these logo's on the page, I tried just  duplacting "`<div id="container"></div>`" a bunch of times in the HTML code. That didn't work:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/9n9ft9ks/5/

So I tried changing the div `id` into a div `class` and I edited all the appropriate javascript & CSS lines that needed to be changed like:

`document.getElementById('container');` 
to:
`document.getElementsByClassName('container');`

and

`#container: {}` to `.container{}`

But that didn't seem to work for me either. The logo doesn't even show up on the page anymore after making these changes, take a look here: https://fiddle.jshell.net/9n9ft9ks/4/

**Summary**

I have a logo with an onClick glass shatter effect. There is only one logo on the page. I need there to be more than one on the page, but can't seem to get it to work myself... If anyone could take a look at the code and try to get it to work so there is more than one logo on the page, i would appreciate it so much! Here is the original jSfiddle one more time: https://fiddle.jshell.net/9n9ft9ks/3/

Comment: Note that when you are using `document.getElementsByClassName('container');` you will be getting multiple items back. I noticed that in the console you are getting an error because you are trying to do `container.appendChild...` to the container which contains multiple elements in an array instead of just 1 element object

Comment: FYI, duplicating an id isn't going to work in most situations. The browser will locate the first instance of the id and ignore the rest because ids are expected to be unique.  non-unique id = unexpected and broken script behavior.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** use a single ID multiple times on the same page.
Use a class instead:

CSS:

```
.className {
    /* attributes: values; */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="className"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your attempt, try changing the `getElementByClassName` for `$('.container')` and then replace the `appendChild` by `append`.

I made it work, but it was a bit messy, it would need more CSS to make the logos not overlap one over each others.

(You can add a style on the second div to see the multiple logos, ex: `<div class="container" style="left: 50px;"></div>`)

Here's the jsfiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/9n9ft9ks/7/

Comment: Thanks for your help! I couldn't get it to work though, unfortunately. If you could post a jSfiddle of this in action, where there is more than one logo on the page... That would be great!

Comment: There are two logos. That's good. But the glass shatter effect doesn't work in your jSfiddle. :( When you click on the logo's, they are supposed to shatter.

Comment: @user1658560 it does shatter, but it appears above.